# Return rvalue reference from function

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, pass-by-rvalue-reference

[CPP Core guidelines F45 states:](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#f45-dont-return-a-t)

> Don't return a T&&.

I want to create some class, and pass the class through a sequence of functions that modify the class.  Then I will either evaluate some members of that class, or store the class in some container, like `std::vector`.

I am trying to do this in a way that the class is constructed exactly once, then destroyed, or moved and the moved-from copy is destroyed, and later the stored copy is destroyed (when the container that I stored it in is destroyed).

In essence, I want to do this:

```
// some class
class foo{}

// construct a foo, with some parameters, and modify it somehow
auto f1 = modify_foo(foo(x, y, z));
// modify the foo some more
auto f2 = modify_foo(f1);
// modify the foo some more
auto f3 = modify_foo(f2);

// use some element of modified foo
auto v = f3.getx();

// maybe store the modified foo in a vector or some other container
vector<foo> vf;
vf.emplace_back(f3);
```

It should be possible to construct the `foo` exactly once, and move the constructed `foo` through any number of modifying functions, then destroy the `foo` exactly once.

In the case of storing the `foo` in a `vector`, an additional copy/move and destroy will have to occur.

I can achieve this behavior, but I can't figure out any way to do it without using this signature for the modify functions:

```
foo&& modify_foo(foo&& in);
```

Here is test code that seems to do what I want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

// A SIMPLE CLASS WITH INSTRUMENTED CONSTRUCTORS
class foo {

public:
    // default constructor
    foo() {
        std::cout << "default construct\n";
    }

    // copy constructor
    foo(foo const &in) : x{ in.x } {
        std::cout << "copy construct\n";
    };

    // copy assignment
    foo& operator=(foo const& in) {
        x = in.x;
        std::cout << "copy assignment\n";
    }

    // move constructor
    foo(foo&& in) noexcept : x(std::move(in.x)) {
        std::cout << "move constructor\n";
    }

    // move assignment
    foo& operator=(foo&& in) noexcept {
        x = std::move(in.x);
        std::cout << "move assignment\n";
        return *this;
    }

    // destructor
    ~foo() {
        std::cout << "destructor\n";
    }

    void inc() {
        ++x;
    }

    int getx() { return x; };

private:

    int x{ 0 };

};
```

Now a function that will take `foo&&`, modify `foo`, return `foo&&`:

```
// A SIMPLE FUNCTION THAT TAKES foo&&, modifies something, returns foo&&
foo&& modify(foo&& in) {
    in.inc();
    return std::move(in);
}
```

Now using the class and modify function:

```
int main(){

    // construct a foo, modify it, return it as foo&&
    auto&& foo1 = modify(foo());

    // modify foo some more and return it
    auto&& foo2 = modify(std::move(foo1));

    // modify foo some more and return it
    auto&& foo3 = modify(std::move(foo2));

    // do something with the modified foo:

    std::cout << foo3.getx();
}
```

This will do exactly what I want.  It will call the constructor once, correctly print `3`, and call the destructor once.

If I do the same thing, except add this:

```
std::vector<foo> fv;
fv.emplace_back(std::move(foo3));
```

It will add one move construct, and another destruct when the `vector` goes out of scope.

This is exactly the behavior I want, and I haven't figured out any other way to get there without returning `foo&&` from the modifier, and using `auto&&` for my intermediate variables, and using `std::move()` on the parameters being passed to the subsequent calls to `modify`.

This pattern is very useful to me.  It is bothering me that I can't resolve this with CPP core guidelines F.45.  The guideline does say:

> Returning an rvalue reference is fine when the reference to the temporary is being passed "downward" to a callee;  Then the temporary is guaranteed to outlive the function call...

Maybe that is what I am doing?

My questions:

1. Is there anything fundamentally wrong, or undefined, in what I am doing?
2. When I do `auto&&`, and hover over the `foo1`, it will show it as a `foo&&`.  I still have to wrap the `foo1` with `std::move(foo1)` to get the modify function to accept it as `foo&&`.  I find this a little strange.  What is the reason for requiring this syntax?

Comment: Temporary lifetime extension does not flow through functions so `auto&& foo1 = modify(foo());` will leave `foo1` as a dangling reference.

Comment: foo() constructs in place, and is passed to modify.  modify moves that foo as a return value, which is 'held' by auto&&foo1, which is passed to the next modify, etc.  I understand that foo1 is useless after it is 'moved' through the next modify, but I don't care about that.  Is it a problem only if I want to refer to foo1 later (which I don't)?

Comment: If you don't care about the return value, why return anything?  If you may or may not use the return value, then you need t make sure you do not pass a temporary to the function if you want the returned reference to be valid.  Right now, your code has UB and is not correct.

Comment: The purpose of the return value is to avoid having to do something like foo1 = modify(modify(modify(modify(foo())))).  I can debug and see the intermediate results also.  In my actual case, modify is a group of different functions that are doing different things to the class.  In reality it might be foo = scale(rotate(filter2(filter1(data(x,y,z))))).  I don't want to copy the class over and over to pass it through functions.  I see no reason why this should require more than 1 construct and destruct with move semantics.

Comment: @ttemple To answer your #2 question, if a variable has a name, by definition it is an lvalue not an rvalue, even if it was taking in as an rvalue reference.  So `foo1` is an lvalue, hence why you need `std::move(foo1)` to make a new rvalue reference from it.

Comment: Makes no sense why the language allows auto&& = n if it is defined to be a dangling reference in all cases.  Seems like if anything returns a &&, there should be a valid way to 'hold' that reference for future consumption.

Comment: @NathanOliver - is this solved by actually constructing the initial foo prior to the modify functions? (instead of as a parameter to the first modify function) Then the foo lives before (and after) the chain of modify functions.

Comment: @ttemple Yes, and if you do that, then instead of using rvalue references you should use lvalue references.

Answer (score 0):

As was correctly pointed out by NathanOliver, attempting to use rvalue ref's was leaving a dangling reference to an object that was being destroyed at the end of the function's life.

**The piece of the puzzle that I was missing was to use `'auto&'`, instead of `'auto'` when returning a ref from a function:**

```
// function taking lvalue ref, returning lvalue ref
foo& modify(foo& in) {
    in.inc();
    return in;
}

{

    auto f =  foo{}; // constructed here

    auto f1 = modify(f); // <-- BAD!!! copy construct occurs here.

    auto& f2 = modify(f); // <-- BETTER - no copy here

} // destruct, destruct
```

If I use auto& to capture the lvalue ref returning from 'modify', no copies are made.  Then I get my desired behavior.  One construct, one destruct.

```
{
    // construct a foo
    foo foo1{};

    // modify some number of times
    auto& foo2 = modify(std::move(foo1));
    auto& foo3 = modify(std::move(foo2));
    auto& foo4 = modify(std::move(foo3));

    std::cout << foo4.getx();
} // 1 destruct here
```